# Scan using nmap on a different network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, nmap

My system is connected to a router and that router is the part of LAN. How do I scan other systems that are a part of the LAN to which my router is connected ? My Router's DHCP allocates C-class private IP address whereas the router has a A class private IP address in the LAN

Comment: well, I usually put in 192.168.xxx.0/24 where xxx is the LANs 3rd octet, and it will scan the whole range. you can also use range notation like this example from the help documentation for nmap: `10.0.0-255.1-254`, DNS cidr like `domain.name.com/24`. its really quite flexible.